# Sending data to another activity on runtime

Tags: android

In my Project I've a child activity with a button, which is inside a library ,

when button of that child activity is clicked,

parent activity should be notified then

parent activity should pass some data to this child activity

which child activity should show.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can reach parent activity parameters, because it is alive. Or you can use EventBus for pass the any data to your chield activity.

Link: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Answer (score 0):

yes this possible by using some global variable file.
use get-set methods in the global file.